# Prevent User Input but Allow Highlighting in TextArea

Tags: java, javafx, textarea

I have a text area that replicates a console output in my GUI. Id like for the user to select highlight and copy the output but not allow them to insert. Is there a way this could be done?

Right now I have a simple textArea editor and Ive tried `terminalText.setDisable(true);`. While this disables userinput it completely disables users from highlighting text as well.

I set my terminal text doing the following:

```
public void printToConsole(String s){
    consoleBuilder.append(s);
    terminalText.setText(consoleBuilder.toString());
}
```

I found that this disables input; however I am now unable to enter text using setText() method above and I cannot highlight:

```
terminalText.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<String>((Change c) -> {
        return null ;
    }));
```

Comment: `terminalText.setEditable(false)`?

Comment: @Slaw wow. not sure how i missed that.. thanks!